# "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique key prop" When they do

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have the below code which I get the error "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique key prop". I checked the docs and as far as I can see the code should be okay as the key used is different for each value and it's on the outermost item.

````
<FlatList
  style={styles.shiftsList}
  numColumns={1}
  data={shifts}
  renderItem={shift => (
    <View key={shift.item.BookingNo} style={styles.row}>
      <Button 
        title="Actions"
        onPress={() => console.log('Action Pressed: ${shift.item.BookingNo}')}
        />
      <Text style={styles.item}>{shift.item.Day}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.item}>{shift.item.Date}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.item}>{shift.item.ShiftType}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.item}>{shift.item.Location}</Text>
    </View> 
  )}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => {item.BookingNo}}
/>

Edit: Shift Data
```const [shifts, setShifts] = useState([{BookingNo: 192, Day: 'Mon', Date: '21/02', ShiftType: 'Night', Start: '08:00:00', Finish: '20:00:00', Location: '23 Tiger woods row'}, {BookingNo: 256, Day: 'Mon', Date: '21/02', ShiftType: 'Night', Start: '08:00:00', Finish: '20:00:00', Location: '25 Tiger woods row'}, {BookingNo: 335, Day: 'Mon', Date: '21/02', ShiftType: 'Night', Start: 
'08:00:00', Finish: '20:00:00', Location: '29 Tiger woods row'}]);
````

Comment: what happens if you do it like this: keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}

Comment: Could you please add your `shifts` data or at least a part of it?

Comment: @Tim added in the shift data

Comment: @yesIamFaded Just tried that now and it gives the same error

Comment: why can't you just console.log your keys and see how they are undefined?

Comment: also, keys should be strings

Comment: @Max i've console logged the shift.item.BookingNo.toString() for each item and they return 192, 256 and 335 so they aren't undefined

Comment: Thanks @Max figured it out, the keyExtractor should've been ```(item, index) => {item.bookingNo.toString()```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that for the key prop you are using shift.item.BookingNo, but for the keyExtractor you used just item.BookingNo.

My guess is that your keyExtractor should look like this:

```
keyExtractor={(shift, index) => {shift.item.BookingNo}}
```

Comment: I tried that and I get this error "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'shift.item.BookingNo')"

Comment: your function returns undefined

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was simply due to the keys needed to be strings.

Changing 
`keyExtractor={(item, index) => {item.BookingNo}}`
Into
`keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.BookingNo.toString()}`

Fixed it for me

Comment: this `keyExtractor={(item, index) => {item.BookingNo.toString()}}` doesn't return anything as there is no `return` statement

Comment: apologies, editing the answer i meant ```keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.BookingNo.toString()}```